# How to query distinct documents that contain Unordered List properties in FileNet P8?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-ce-sql

I am trying to send a dynamically built query to FileNet 5.2 using the .Net API. The Document Class that I am trying to query has three properties in the select list that have a cardinality of Unordered List and type String. When I send over the query with the `DISTINCT` keyword, FileNet returns this error:

> Can't select property with "distinct": RouteNumber.

Here is an example SQL statement that is getting passed to FileNet:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    td.DrawingNumber, 
    td.ProjectTitle, 
    td.WorkArea, 
    td.RouteNumber, 
    td.City, 
    td.County, 
    td.DrawingNumberAssignedYear, 
    td.Comment, 
    td.MajorVersionNumber, 
    td.IsCurrentVersion 
FROM TrafficDocument AS td WITH EXCLUDESUBCLASSES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RoadwaySegment AS rwy WITH EXCLUDESUBCLASSES ON td.ID = rwy.ParentObjectID 
WHERE td.IsCurrentVersion = True 
    AND '104' IN RouteNumber 
ORDER BY td.DrawingNumber, td.TrafficPlanDiscipline 
OPTIONS (TIMELIMIT 180)
```

I need the `DISTINCT` keyword because the joining document class, RoadwaySegment, is causing duplicates but it is needed in the query because their values can be filtered against as well.

So how can I achieve my goal of querying FileNet and retrieving unique results?

Answer (score 0):

Is `RouteNumber` an orderable property? Only orderable ones are allowed for queries with `DISTINCT`.

[DISTINCT restrictions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/query_sql_syntax_rel_queries.htm#query_sql_syntax_rel_queries__distinct_restriction):

> A `DISTINCT` query can be performed only when all
>   of the SELECTed properties are orderable. For example, if property P1
>   is not orderable (Binary type, or String type with UsesLongColumn),
>   the following query produces an error message:
>
> `SELECT DISTINCT P1 From Object1`